# meteor iron router dynamic segment not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, segment, iron-router

I've been looking into meteor and it's awesome! I've been looking for routing solutions and I found 'iron-router' which is cool, I managed to get the get static pages working with templates but when I go to /posts/123, the page does not render. I have been following a video on this site

https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/q8QWX5e7PTu8BEReY

Here's my code

blog.js EDITED

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

Router.configure({
  layout: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundtemplate: 'notFound'
});

Router.map( function (){
  this.route('posts', {
    path: '/',
    waitOn: function () {
      return App.subs.posts;
    },
    data: {
      posts: function () {
        return Posts.find({}, {sort: {order: 1}});
      }
    }
  });

  this.route('postShow', {
    path: '/posts/:_id'
  });
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('posts', function () {
    return Posts.find({}, {sort: {order: 1}});
  });

  Meteor.publish('post', function (id) {
    return Posts.find({_id: id});
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  App = {
    subs: {
      posts: Meteor.subscribe('posts')
    }
  };

  PostShowController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'postShow',
    before: function () {
      var _id = this.params._id;

      if(App.subs.post)
        App.subs.post.stop();

      App.subs.post = Meteor.subscribe('post', _id);
    },
    data: {
      body: function () {
        return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
      }
    },
    run: function () {
      this.render('postShow');
    }
  });
}
```

blog.html

```
<head>
    <title>IronRouter</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="layout">
    <div class="container">
        <aside class="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-inner">
                {{yield 'sidebar'}}
            </div>
        </aside>

        <section class="content">
            <div class="content-inner">
                {{yield}}
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="notFound">
  <h1>Not Found</h1>
</template>

<template name="loading">
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
</template>

<template name="posts">
  <h1>Posts</h1>
  <ul>
    {{#each posts}}
    <li>{{> postListItem}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="postListItem">
    <a href="{{pathFor 'postShow'}}">
        {{title}}
    </a>
</template>

<template name="postShow">
  <p>
    {{body}}
  </p>
</template>

<template name="postShowSidebar">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: In your controller, your context is defined by 'data', and there you're using Posts, but you are calling 'waitOn' with App.subs.post. This may mean that Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id}) returns empty at the moment your page renders

Comment: Hi Petrov, I've tried removing 'waitOn' from the controller but I'm still not getting anything back :/

Comment: I'm assuming the superfluous ` at the end of blog.js is not actually in your code, right?

Comment: nope (i just doubled checked), it would've felt uber silly if that was the problem all along haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the video and it may be a little out of date. My apologies. I would do the following:

1. Change `layout: 'layout'` to `layoutTemplate: 'layout'`
2. Remove the `run` method from your controller. That method actually does a lot and so if you want to override rendering you can use the `action` method instead. But in your case, you don't need to do any of that because it will happen automatically.
3. This is sort of unrelated, but you don't need to stop the subscription yourself. It turns out, Meteor and iron-router will do this automatically when the computation is stopped (i.e. when you navigate to a new route).

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply Chris! I managed to get it working! but I've noticed that 'this.params._id' isn't available in the 'data' method but it works in the 'before' method so I created a variable outside the controller, assigned it in the 'before' and retrieved it in the 'data'

Comment: Great! That's strange about this.params not available in the data function. That would be a legitimate bug you could file on Github. I'll make a note to take a look too. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your PostShowController to the corresponding route:

```
this.route('postShow', {
  path: '/posts/:_id',
  controller: 'PostShowController'
});
```

Comment: this isn't necessary - from the docs : "When the route is run, it will look for a global object named "PostShowController"

Comment: Yes you are correct Petrov according to the docs.  Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but in your controller you say

```
data: function () {
  return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
},
```

but in your template you are using {{body}}, which I don't see being assigned anything anywhere. Doesn't that need to be as:

```
data: {
  body: function () {
    return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Christian, I just tried that but unfortunately, it didn't work, I assumed that the {{body}} is retrieved from the selected 'Post' (so that in each 'Post' there's are 'title' and 'body'), I may be wrong though as the schema is not specified in the video.

Comment: I've set up your code in my machine and noticed that the data function is never executed. Couldn't figure out why, but thought I'd mention it in case it helps. The run function executes though.

Comment: Thanks Christian! I appreciate the effort, I'll take a closer look at the data function, hopefully I can get it working asap!